# What has happened to my camera in Blender 3.6?

Tags: camera

i don't know what's wrong, maybe i did something wrong?
camera scale is 1, near far are 10cm and 1km.
it happens in any file, even the blender templates, even if i delete and add new cameras.

[image: camera looks weird in blender 3.6]

[image: camera settings]

Comment: it looks like a bug, what does it give if you close and re-open Blender or open a new file?

Comment: If the above doesn't work: Is that the default new scene or a blend file you opened? Where does that file come from and do you know which version it was made from?

Comment: "*i don't know what's wrong*" Neither do we, you didn't provide enough details to diagnose the issue, your screenshot is severely cropped and doesn't show the UI or relevant properties, so we can't diagnose the issue. Could you edit your question and provide more details, including a full uncropped screenshot showing camera settings and viewport properties so we don't have to blindly guess around what the issue is?

Comment: In addition, you can also upload your file on [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) and [edit] your question to embed the download link. That way we can even check the file directly if extra explanations and screenshots aren't enough.

Comment: Please include a share, so we can try to reproduce on our own installations

Comment: Which version of blender is this? Have you tried (re)installing the latest stable version?

Comment: It's 3.6 as it says in the title of this question

Comment: There is no 3.6, there is 3.6.0, 3.6.1 or the daily 3.6.2. I ask this because it could be a bug that got fixed in the minor updates of that version and reporting a bug would require you to test the latest version too. Regardless, have you tried the other things me and other people mentioned?

Comment: 3.6 is 3.6.0; no one has asked me to try anything yet. uploading a file anywhere is pointless since it happens no matter what file is being used. even with a factory reset.

Comment: Then use the menu Help > Report a bug.

Comment: https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/111161
I submitted this as a bug and turns out others have faced this issue and it's got something to do with the Mesa drivers, it will prolly be fixed in Blender 4.0!